What's the easiest way to include curl in bazel c++?
I am developing LLM Agent in C++ with Bazel build system,
However, I am not sure what's the best way to include curl.h in C++ with Bazel. I tried to add
curl WORKSPACE
in my workspace and I created another BUILD file called libcurl.BUILD.
But when I try to run it, it keeps asking me to install more packages like boringssl, zlib, grpc, etc...
I am getting lost in this fan out and I am wondering what is the best way to install curl? In python it's as simple as pip install XXX.
Tried: Bazel installation in workspace file

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

No clue about bazel, but curl can be built with a bunch of options that enable/disable features. Many of these features require other libraries, which is what you're seeing here. Unfortunately in the screenshot, the tool tip covers up the actual url for libcurl (another great reason to never post screenshots of code), but I'm guessing you're using a pre-built version with lots of features. You can build libcurl yourself or look for another version that's more reduced.

No English native speaker myself but it sounds okay to me. The word "please" usually softens a sentence. Actually, I commented thus because it's the canonical link to make people aware not to post images of code. You'll find it in the linked page. You might suggest an edit with a more friendly wording. Improvements are always welcome.

An easy but not hermetic approach is to use the system installed curl lib (works good on Ubuntu and macOS):
cc_binary(
    name = "testbed",
    srcs = ["testbed.cpp"],
    linkopts = [
        "-lcurl",
    ],
)

I use this approach here.
If you have Bazel 7 or newer you can use Bzlmod. Luckily the Bazel Central Registry offers libcurl. Add to your MODULE.bazel file:
bazel_dep(name = "curl", version = "8.7.1")

You can now add to the deps attribute in your BUILD files @curl//:curl

https://github.com/hedronvision/bazel-make-cc-https-easy is my final solution. It includes an example that tell how how to work on WORKSPACE and build files.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
